# How to convert breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix to Map[String,Value]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I need to transform the DenseMatrix to Map[String,[Value]]. The key will first row's each value. The values of corresponding key will be column.

```
eg:

Solid liquid Gas 
Stone Water  Oxygen
Gold  kerosene Nitrogen

So map will be Map(Solid -> [Stone,Gold],Liquid -> [Water,kerosene],Gas -> [Oxygen,Nitrogen])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this:

```
val mat = DenseMatrix(("Solid", "liquid", "gas"), ("Stone", "Water", "Oxygen"), ("Gold", "kerosene", "Nitrogen"))

{
  for {
    i <- 0 until mat.rows
  } yield (mat(i, 0) -> mat(i, 1 until mat.cols))
} toMap
```